# C# factory construction not working

Tags: c#, generics

I am obviously doing something wrong here, but the question is how do i get it working? I got the following code

Note: ParameterEventStreamRef inherits from Parameter, same goes for the StStvariants.

```
public void DoStuff(Parameter[] parameters)
{
    var Parameters = parameters.Select(x => parameterConverterFactory.GetParameterConverter(x).ToJsonClass(x)).ToArray();
}

public class ParameterConverterFactory: IParameterConverterFactory
{
    public IStackStateJsonConverter<StStParameter, Parameter> GetParameterConverter(StStParameter arg)
    {
        if (arg.GetType() == typeof(StStParameterEventStreamRef))
            return new JsonParameterEventStreamRefConverter();
        throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException(arg.GetType().FullName);
    }

public class JsonParameterEventStreamRefConverter : JsonParameterConverter, IStackStateJsonConverter<StStParameterEventStreamRef, ParameterEventStreamRef>
{

    public ParameterEventStreamRef ToJsonClass(StStParameterEventStreamRef arg, ParameterEventStreamRef source = null)
    {
        if (source == null)
            source = new ParameterEventStreamRef();
        base.ToJsonClass(arg, source);
        source.var1 = arg.var1;
        source.var2 = arg.var2;
        return source;
    }
}

public class JsonParameterConverter : JsonNodeConverter, IStackStateJsonConverter<StStParameter, Parameter>
{
    public Parameter ToJsonClass(StStParameter arg, Parameter source = null)
    {
        if (source == null)
            source = new Parameter();
        source.var0 = arg.var0;

        return source;
    }
}
```

Problem is: the factory is returning the correct Converter, but when the converter is called, it is "Skipping" the JsonParameterEventStreamRefConverter and going directly to the JsonParameterConverter. I think the reason for this is a part of the logic is done compile-time, the other run-time.

Comment: Have you stepped through it to see that the correct type is being returned?

Comment: yes i did, problem is in what is being done compiletime and what is being done runtime. I know C# generates each class or method for every type that is calling that class or method. So what I'm guessing is it will always call only the parameterconverter, because the compiler doesn't know it could also be a derived type. 

What I am looking for is the best way to solve this (I posted a messy solution below, but i hope there is a cleaner way).

Comment: The code you've posted is incomplete - it's unclear which classes inherit from each other and what interfaces they implement. Specifically, the definition of the `IStackStateJsonConverter<T, U>` interface is missing. I suspect it contains a method `Parameter ToJsonClass(StStParameter arg, Parameter source = null)` - if so, it shouldn't be surprising that `JsonParameterEventStreamRefConverter.ToJsonClass` isn't called, because it has a different signature and therefore doesn't conform to that interface. But again, without complete, working code that's just guesswork.

Comment: You read the Note: ParameterEventStreamRef inherits from Parameter, same goes for the StStvariants? But yes, that is what i think is happening, what i'm looking for is a clean way to implement this. See my own solution below that has 2 responsibilities.

Comment: I read the note, but it's ambiguous and not enough to get the code working. Either way, I'd start by making `JsonParameterConverter.ToJsonClass` virtual, so you can override it in `JsonParameterEventStreamRefConverter`. The overriding method would need to have the same parameter types so it may need to check that it received the correct argument types - if it needs to access anything specific to the StreamRef classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DoStuff() you're calling the ToJsonClass() method. Even though that you 'x' could be any descendant from Parameter, the runtime will not know which one it is.
It will look for the ToJsonClass() signature that best matches the signature: ToJsonClass(Parameter). The JsonParamterConverter has a method that matches this exactly, so that's the best match.

You could try replacing the ToJsonClass() in JsonParameterStreamRef with something like this:

```
public override Parameter ToJsonClass(StStParameter arg, Parameter source = null)
{
    if (arg.GetType() == typeof (StStParameterEventStreamRef))
    {
        return ToJsonClass(arg as StStParameterEventStreamRef, source as ParameterEventStreamRef);
    }
    return base.ToJsonClass(arg, source); // or throw an exception if this is an error.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a working solution to the problem, but if you can come up with a better solution, please.

```
    public Parameter GetConverterFactory_AndDo_ToJsonClass(StStParameter stStParameter)
    {
        if (stStParameter.GetType() == typeof (StStParameterEventStreamRef))
            return new JsonParameterEventStreamRefConverter().ToJsonClass(stStParameter as StStParameterEventStreamRef);
        throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException(stStParameter.GetType().FullName);
    }
```